# Using sudo aptitude remove Genymotion

Tags: genymotion

I am using `sudo aptitude remove Genymotion` command to remove genymotion and it shows:-

```
 kde-l10n-engb{u} liballegro4.4{u} libbonoboui2-0{u} 
  libbonoboui2-common{u} libgnome2-0{u} libgnome2-bin{u} 
  libgnomecanvas2-0{u} libgnomecanvas2-common{u} libgnomeui-0{u} 
  libgnomeui-common{u} libidl-2-0{u} libllvm3.8{u} libllvm3.8:i386{u} 
  libmircommon5{u} libopencv-calib3d2.4v5{u} libopencv-features2d2.4v5{u} 
  libopencv-flann2.4v5{u} libopencv-legacy2.4v5{u} libopencv-ml2.4v5{u} 
  liborbit2{u} libpango1.0-0{u} python-appindicator{u} 
  python-babel-localedata{u} python-gconf{u} python-gnome2{u} 
  python-gobject{u} python-pyorbit{u} python3-babel{u} python3-psutil{u} 
  python3-pyaudio{u} python3-tz{u} python3-xlib{u} swh-plugins{u} 
  ubuntu-core-launcher{u} wing-data{u} xprintidle{u}
```

It is removing these packages, should I proceed.

Comment: Please provide the full output.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You may proceed as these are the packages which were automatically installed while installing Genymotion or are just companion packages and removing them will not have effect on any other application and you can run this command also which will remove no longer required packages         `sudo apt autoremove` and then remove Genymotion